# Mysqli not working with eclipse 4

Tags: php, mysql, eclipse, mysqli

After i upgrade to Eclipse 4 from 3.8, i'm not able to use msqli in my PHP code anymore.
when i call fx. mysqli_connect() it returns this error "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function foo\mysqli_connect()".
But when i'm inside the code, it finds everything inside "mysqli.php" without any problems.

Here is some to show what i'm doing.

```html
<?php
$server = "192.168.1.5";
$user = "user";
$pass = "password";
$DB = "Database";

$conn=mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pass,$DB);

if (!$conn)
{
 die('Could not connect: ' . $this->conn->mysqli_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully\n";
```

could anyone help me out here?
also this is on Ubuntu 14.04 if that might help.

Comment: Ah, your title is wrong then. Php do work fine, is only eclipse that now work correctly.

Comment: can i edit the title(im pretty new here)

@donald123 what about the namespaces? It's the same program just new editor.

Comment: Do you have mysqli extension installed?

Comment: I would think so. But just to be sure how can i check?